# Слова в Memo1 перенести в DBGRID в определенный столбик

Tags: delphi

У меня есть Слова в Memo1(TMemo), который надо перенести в DBGRID1 в определенный столбик. Как это можно сделать и Можно ли кодом пример?

Comment: dbgrid - это только окошечко для наблюдения за набором данных. Так что вносите данные в нужное поле ("столбец") соответствующего DataSet

Comment: поменять TMemo на TDbMemo и связать с датасетом, если заменить  надо значение в одной строке, а не всем столбце

Answer (score 1):

Значение необходимо записывать в связанный источник данных.

```
DBGRID1.DataSource.DataSet.Edit;
DBGRID1.DataSource.DataSet.FieldByName('ОпределенныйСтолбик').Value := Memo1.Text;
DBGRID1.DataSource.DataSet.Post;
```